# Which of these licenses is the most restrictive in its licensing terms?

Tags: licensing

**I'm setting up a new project and I want to choose a license that is as limiting as possible while still being open source.**

- Apache License 2.0
- Artistic License/GPL
- Eclipse Public License 1.0
- GNU General Public License v2
- GNU General Public License v3
- GNU Lesser General Public License
- MIT License
- Mozilla Public License 1.1
- New BSD License

Comment: http://www.gnu.org/licenses/ Also, feel free to make your own in the form of 'You can only use this for X'. It's completely up to you. You just need to have the ability to enforce it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because **it is about licensing or legal issues**, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274964/1402846) for details, and the [help/on-topic] for more.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This really depends on what you mean by 'restrictive.' If you mean, which one make it hardest to use free code in your proprietary application without giving credit to the authors of the code - its the GPL. The opposite of that would be the BSD license. However, I like that license because it makes it harder for people to use my hard work for free without contributing derivative works back to the world. It's free as in 'free speech' - not free beer. So, if you are looking for free beer, stay away from GPL code.

Comment: I think what you mean is that the GPL places the highest burden on users of my open source code to provide attribution to me while BSD places the least stringent requirements on those users. If so, it sounds like GPL is what I need. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I mean - if you want your code and derivative works to stay free, the GPL is the way to go.

Answer (score 10):

**AGPL** .. the most restrictive one